# Sails v1.0 skips api/blueprints directory

Tags: sails.js

I have upgraded to sails v1.0 from v0.12

in sails v0.12 i had a directory **api/blueprints** that contained **find.js, add.js etc..** that override the basic blueprint function for every model.

this doesn't seem to work under sails v1.0,

has it been moved? what should i do to override every blueprint action for my every controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this hook for overriding blueprints in 1.0
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-custom-blueprints

Source:
Sails 1.0 docs
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api